# c# check if 2 string includes the same chars

Tags: c#, string, compare

I created 3 `strings`:

```
string a = "abcdgfg";
string b = "agbfcd";
string c = "axcvn";
```

I want to create the following check but i can't find out how:
Need to check if in `string a` and `string b` there are the same latters (never mind the order or if a latter shown more than once, just need to check if the same latter appears on both strings).
Then i need to do the same check for `string a` and `string c`.

as you can see: `string a` and `string b` have the same latters, `stringa a` and `string c` don't.

after i do the checking i simply print a massage if the strings have the same latter or not

Can anyone show me how to do the cheking?

**Edit**:

after check "a" and "c", it o should print the first latter that came up and not match between "a" and "c"

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to use a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) and it's [`SetEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var aSet = new HashSet<char>(a);
var bSet = new HashSet<char>(b);
bool abSame = aSet.SetEquals(b);
```

**Edit**

> after check "a" and "c", it o should print the first latter that came
>   up and not match between "a" and "c"

Then you can use [`HashSet.SymmetricExceptWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336848(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (!abSame)
{
    aSet.SymmetricExceptWith(bSet);
    Console.WriteLine("First letter that is either in a and not in b or in b and not in a: " + aSet.First()); 
}
```

By the way, this can also replace the `SetEquals` check:

```
aSet.SymmetricExceptWith(bSet); // removes all characters which are in both
if (aSet.Any())                 // missing charaters in one of both strings
{
    Console.WriteLine("First letter that is either in a and not in b or in b and not in a: " + aSet.First()); 
}
```

---

The original answer using `Except` + `Any` had a subtle bug. Checking the length is not sufficient if there are duplicates. So you need to check from both directions or use `Distinct` first. Both approaches are inefficient compared to the `HashSet.SetEquals`-method which is a O(n) operation.

```
bool abSame = !a.Except(b).Any() && !b.Except(a).Any();
```

Comment: Your first idea worked, iprefered to do it with string extension instead using HashSet (which i am not even familiar with). can think for something like your first idea without the lenght checking (because you say it have a bug)... i also edded my first post, can you help me with that too? :)

Comment: @user3396397: it works only if you use `!Except+Any` from both sides, the Length-check is not sufficient. Consider that a is `"aaa"` and b `"ab"`. `HashSet<Char>.SetEquals` is readable and more efficient.

Comment: Now i understand what `HashSet` does, this is great for me, thank :)

Comment: can you help me with my eddit?   after check "a" and "c", it should print the first latter that came up and not match between "a" and "c"

Comment: @user3396397: i have edited my answer. You can use `SymmetricExceptWith` to find all characters that are missing in one of both strings. You could even use it in the first place and check `aSet.Any()` afterwards. That would replace the `SetEquals` check.

Answer (score 4):

```
private bool HaveSameLetters(string a, string b)
{       
     return a.All(x => b.Contains(x)) && b.All(x => a.Contains(x));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Need to check if in string a and string b there are the same latters (never mind the order or if a latter shown more than once, just need to check if the same latter appears on both strings).

You can do it like this:

```
bool same = a.Distinct().OrderBy(c => c)
           .SequenceEqual(b.Distinct().OrderBy(c => c));
```

This simply sorts the characters of two strings and checks if the two ordered sequence are equal. You can use the same method for `a` and `c`.

Comment: What about "or if a latter shown more than once" bit?

Comment: A little bit inefficient, isn't it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter for huge strings, may be :)